# Feature counter loading incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties, notifications, navigation

I was browsing on So when I noticed something odd. The "featured" tab that contains all the questions with bountys on them displayed its counter at 0. I tried reloading the page to check if it was just a caching error, but the problem recurred. When I then clicked on the "Questions" tab, the features bar loaded properly.

I tried closing my browser and going back to So and the problem happened again. Its relatively minor bug, but I thought it was worth noting. I've included photos of both the broken counter and working counter.

**Not-Working:**

[image: Bugged Featured]

**Working:**

[image: Working Featured]

Comment: Norepro, sorry.

Comment: So then it must be a local problem? I was able to reproduce it every time I went back to So.

Comment: Maybe try clearing your cache?

Comment: Seemed to be a cache problem, but why would it happen in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps it was using the last updated number, but fetching that number failed. Iunno, though. I'm not an official source of info for such things.

Comment: @Emrakul, well thanks for the input, I appreciate it. It really is a minor bug and the problem seemed to be momentary, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I've seen this happen a number of times.  Right now, [Japanese Language.SE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/) is oscillating between 0 and 1, although the sole bounty is now roughly a day old.  (It shows as "0 featured" most of the time, but I see "1 featured" sometimes.  This inconsistency may be why the bug is incorrectly marked as "norepro".)