# Feature count different in MainPage and in tabbed page

Tags: support

Featured count in [Main page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured)

[image]

And Featured count in [question tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

[image]

As you can notice there is a difference of 2 questions. So, I'm curious whether questions were omitted or if it is a count error.

Note: I have Android tag as my Favourite and no tag in ignored tag list.

PS: I'm not sure if it's really a bug so adding supprt tag instead. Also those values may change.

Comment: Related: [Feature counter loading incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204753/feature-counter-loading-incorrectly)

Comment: Now its showing 397 in main and 396 in question tab

Comment: @JoshC the other question points at count become 0 which is not the case here..

Comment: Yea - you're right, they are definitely related though. It is probably caching. Aside from that the system seems to be having minor problems at the moment anyways.

Comment: Related http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/why-featured-tab-shows-the-count-wrongly

Comment: Sorry but I really don't see the issue here (the gap is only two posts).. each one of those pages was opened in a different time, so why would you expect the same count? Many things can happen in a brief moment..